# How to find css/js files on a server for specified application that uses docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am using: https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS for mail by installing it on our ubuntu server. It uses Docker containers, I tried to figure out how to access application files like css/js in those containers, but have not been successful. Furthest I got was going to `/var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINERID` but once I view contents of the containers they are all the same and css/js files are no where to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to access those files is running an interactive shell in the container. To do that you can run `docker run -i -t <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash`.

Regarding the files, docker images and containers are composed by layers and volumes. The files you are looking for will be located probably in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers` (depending of your layer filesystem), but you can omit accessing to the files directly and get them in a interactive session.